# How to return the beginning of a string in php?

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>E6 L7</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
    <form method="post">
    Detailed Content of the article:
    <br>
    <textarea name="full" cols="80" rows="5"></textarea>
    <br>
    Trimmed Display with the number of characters:
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="trim">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="sm" value="Post">
    </form>
    <?php 
    $fullcontent = $_POST['full'];
    $trimnumber = $_POST['trim'];



     ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

It looks like:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onlA6.jpg)

[image]
How can I get "She is a" from the string in the screenshot? Or more generally, when I enter a number in the field "Trimmed Display with a number of characters", **I would get it cut off nicely with whole words cut?**. That means it will cut out "She is a" or "She is a very" but never result in "She is a ve".

Comment: Why did you not include your PHP code in the example? All we can do without it and with your errors is assume you've done something like `$_GET['full']` instead of `$_POST['full']`.

Comment: there is no action specified in the form. after submitting form, where will be the code runs?

Comment: @JeesKDenny To the current page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use php's [substr function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php).

Example: `echo substr('String goes here', 0, 5);` will output only `Strin`.